# Win Server 2022 FTP issue

Tags: windows, ftp, windows-server-2022

We have 2 web servers one is Server 2016 the second is Server 2022. We moved a site from the 2016 box to the 2022 box and FTP stopped working. We did configure FTP the same on both servers. The FTP service is running. the ftp client shows : Status: Resolving address of [www.XXXX.com](http://www.XXXX.com) Status: Connecting to 74.XXX.XXX.XXX:21... Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message... Error: Connection closed by server Error: Could not connect to server

The FTP logs do not show any connection. I turned the firewall on the 2022 box off completely and same issue. It is not a firewall in front of the 2022 box, because the 2016 box works.

I even installed WSFtp disabled IIS's FTP and same issue.

The is no virus scanner running on the 2022 box yet.

Any help please!

Thank you in advance

Comment: **It is not a firewall in front of the 2022 box, because the 2016 box works** - So you allow unrestricted access to the servers? Are they exposed to the internet?